# How fill area under each line separately with Plots.jl?

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I tried fill area under each line separately with Plots.jl. Here my code:

```
using Plots;
gr()
Data = Tuple{Float64,Float64}[]
p=plot([0.1,1.0],[1,1],fill=(0,:green))
push!(p,[1.6,1.8],[1,1])
push!(p,[2.2,2.5],[1,1])
push!(p,[3.2,3.5],[1,1])
```

but this not work:

[image: result]

How make this correctly if it possibly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you want, but I think you're trying to cover rectangular areas. Here is one way to do it:

```
p=plot([0.1, 1.0], [1, 1],fill=(0,:green))
append!(p, 1, [1.0,1.6,1.6,1.8], [0,0,1,1])
append!(p, 1, [1.8,2.2,2.2,2.5], [0,0,1,1])
append!(p, 1, [2.5,3.2,3.2,3.5], [0,0,1,1])
```

Note that you need to specify the "zero areas" too, otherwise the area graph will join over the "data gap" resulting in an uninterrupted green area. (equally if you only append single points instead of "zero" and "one" segments, you'll get a linear rise instead of a steep rise).

[image]

Comment: thanks, that's work. May you explain for what need second argument in function append?

Comment: I'm only guessing myself because I don't really use this, but I think it's to specify which plot component you want to append to. e.g., the docs say if you use the `plot!` command, you will create a second plot object / component in the same figure, on top of the first one. So I think the second argument to `append!` is an integer which allows you to specify e.g. if you're appending to the first plot in the window, or the second you created on top.